# How can I manage stored procedure rights of the role in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqlroleprovider, sql-revoke

I want to create three SQL Server database roles.

1. That can CREATE, ALTER and EXECUTE all stored procedures in database
2. That can only EXECUTE all stored procedures in database
3. That have no access to any stored procedures in database

I have created the roles, but I'm facing issues while REVOKE their permissions.

I have executed

```
REVOKE CREATE PROCEDURE TO [ROLE NAME]
```

to revoke the permissions to create the procedure and it executed successfully.

But I got error while executing this statement:

> Error: Incorrect syntax near 'ALTER'.

I am very new to SQL server role rights so I might be completely wrong with my approach.

Please guide me to achieve my goal in correct way.

Thanks

Comment: What did you use to give the `ROLE` the ability to `ALTER` Stored Procedures? `GRANT ALTER PROCEDURE TO YourRole;` would have given you the same error.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation [Create a Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15):

> ### Permissions
>
> Requires CREATE PROCEDURE permission in the database and ALTER
>   permission on the schema in which the procedure is being created.

Therefore just giving `CREATE PROCEDURE` on it's own won't allow you to create a procedure. In fact, giving a `ROLE` the `CREATE PROCEDURE` permission, and not `ALTER` on the schema will result in the below error:

> The specified schema name "dbo" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.

There is no `ALTER PROCEDURE` permissions, therefore, for a member of a `ROLE` to be able to both `CREATE` and `ALTER` a `PROCEDURE` you would need to do:

```
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO YourRole;
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::dbo TO YourRole; --Replace with appropriate schema name
```

This, however, will also enable to user to `ALTER` anyprocedures on said schema. Ut also enable those in the role to `ALTER` other objects on the schema as well (such as tables) though.

If your `ROLE` has permissions to `ALTER` the procedures and you want to remove that, you would need to run the below:

```
REVOKE ALTER ON SCHEMA::dbo TO YourRole;
```

This will, as mentioned, also revoke their ability to `ALTER` any other objects on said schema.

*Remember, `REVOKE` doesn't `DENY`, it simply means that the `USER` won't inherited that permission from that `ROLE` any more. If the `USER` has the permission from a different `ROLE`, or they have the permission themselves, they will be able to continue to use the permission. If you must stop a `USER` from performing an action, regardless of any other permissions, they must have the `DENY` permission.*

Comment: So that means if I execute REVOKE ALTER ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [ROLE NAME]. Then it will not allow user to ALTER table, function, view anything?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) That can CREATE, ALTER and EXECUTE all stored procedures in
>   database

That's the db_owner role, or the CONTROL permission on the database.  Anyone with all those permissions can escalate their own privileges to a database-level admin.  So don't try.

> 2) That can only EXECUTE all stored procedures in database

GRANT EXECUTE TO [SomeRole]

> 3) That have no access to any stored procedures in database

A user has no access to any stored procedure unless you grant permissisions or add them to a role that has permissions.